# How do you get the current cursor position (in a textarea) whenever the cursor or arrow key is pressed DOWN?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, selection, caret

I am trying to get the position of the text cursor immediately after one clicks **down** the mouse to reposition it. The issue is that `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` do not return the most current position of the cursor, since the "new" position doesn't get stored until the click is **released**. The code snippet shows this problem when you try to reposition the caret with the mouse.

This is strange because I can technically type at the "new" position as soon as the mouse is clicked down, but `selectionStart` still returns the old position. If the cursor position can clearly change without having to release the click, then how do you access the new position without having to wait for the `mouseup`?

(this also seems to be a problem for tracking cursor position after keydowns)

```js
const input = document.getElementById('myInput');
input.addEventListener('mousedown', showposition); // click

function showposition() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += " " + input.selectionStart;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `click` event instead of the `mousedown` event. This is because, at the point when the mousedown event is triggered, the `selectionStart` would not have been updated which is why you keep getting the previous values.

Click event on the other hand is a combination of `mouseup` + `mousedown` event which captures one complete mouse click and returns the expected cursor position value.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('myInput');
input.addEventListener('click', showposition); // click

function showposition(event) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += " " + event.target.selectionStart;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: thank you! is there an event that takes into account only the mousedown event (and not mouseup)? for example, if you click on index 2 to reposition the cursor, type a random string, and then release the mouse, then it would still output "2" instead of the endpoint?

Comment: did you find an answer for this? can you access only the mousedown event?