# How to put value to mouse focused position Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have angular form textarea

```
<textarea class="form-control"                        
                        id="message"
                        formControlName="message"
                        (focus)="onFocusEvent($event)"
></textarea>
```

and button that add text to the end of

```
<button (click)=addText()></button>

addText() {
const customText: string = 'customText';
this.form.setValue({message: this.form.get('message').value + '\n' + customText});
}
```

I'd like to add customText to place based on where mouse is located on now.
How can I determine that place? possible using onFocus event?

Comment: [possibly duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310186/how-do-you-get-the-current-cursor-position-in-a-textarea-whenever-the-cursor-o)

Comment: this value is always 0 no matter which position of textarea I'm putting cursor

Answer (score 0):

Determining the mouse position is easy with Rxjs. Look at the following example:

[Stackblitz - MouseMove](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t6mdlm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

After this, you can create a method that determines the message to display based on the mouse result.

I hope this helps.